# Cant send string array from java server to android client using socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, objectoutputstream

I am trying to create an android application that interact with the java server. The server needs to send a string array to the client. The client(android) receives the string array and need to display it in a listview. I try the following code but the client didn't print the received string in logcat.

**Android Client**

```
ObjectInputStream objectinput=new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
operation=(String[])objectinput.readObject();
Log.i("operation",operation[0]);
```

**Java Server**

```
ObjectOutputStream objectoutput=new ObjectOutputStream( clientSocket.getOutputStream());
objectoutput.writeObject(G.opername);
objectoutput.flush();
```

**Full Server Code**

```
public class Project {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String message;
private static byte[] bytearray;
private static Global G = new Global();
private static String msg = "Hai";

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7575); // Server socket

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 7575");
    }

    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 7575");

    while (true) {
        try {

            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client
                                                  // connection
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            Dbsearch db = new Dbsearch();
            db.search(message);
            System.out.println(message);
            inputStreamReader.close();
            ObjectOutputStream objectoutput = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            objectoutput.writeObject(G.opername);
            objectoutput.flush();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
        }
    }

}
```

}

**GLOBAL CLASS**

```
 class Global
 {
      public static String opername[]=new String[100];
 }
```

I try socket programming code seperately in a project but it also dont display any result in my android screen.

**Java Server Code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
public class Server
{
    private static String msg="Hai";
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7676);  //Server socket
            System.out.println("Server Started listening in 7676");
    clientSocket=serverSocket.accept();
    PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
    writer.write(msg);
    System.out.println("Message Send");
    writer.flush();
    clientSocket.close();
         } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 7676");
         }
}
}
```

**Android Client Code**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
         private EditText ed;
         private Socket sc;
         private String msg="";
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         try 
         {
          sc=new Socket("10.0.2.2",7676);
          InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream());
          BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(isr);
              msg=bf.readLine();
              Log.i("message",msg);
          ed.setText(msg);
          sc.close();
         } 
         catch (UnknownHostException e) 
         {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
         } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
   }
```

Comment: Any exception while reading it from socket's input stream?

Comment: No it doesn't display any exception. i send a string from client to server its working but server to client is not working.

Comment: do you mind posting full server code

Comment: I post my server code.

Comment: you never assign anything to `G`

Comment: or probably `G.opername` gets some default value when instantiated. Could you post your `Global` class as well?

Comment: ya sure.. i will post it

Comment: Please post Global class here and also is there any exception while writing array to socket?

Comment: @user3243259 your `opername` is array of nulls, you instantiate it but you never assign any string to `opername[i]` that's why you don't get anything in client

Comment: @user3243259 you should get `"operation" "null"` in your logs

Comment: No i dont get a tag named operation in my logcat